# How to get midpoint of polyline in java arcobjects

Tags: arcobjects, java

Here I want the midpoint of every polyline and add that point to List.

```c#
List<IPoint> pList = new ArrayList<IPoint>();
Polyline polyline = null;       
IPoint point = null;
for(int i=0;i<pFeatureLayerList.size();i++)
{
    IFeatureClass pFeatureClass = pFeatureLayerList.get(i).getFeatureClass();
    int numFeatures = pFeatureClass.featureCount(null);     
    if(pFeatureClass.getShapeType()==com.esri.arcgis.geometry.esriGeometryType.esriGeometryPolyline)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<numFeatures; j++)
        {
             IFeature pFeature = pFeatureClass.getFeature(j);
             polyline = (Polyline)pFeature.getShape();
             point = polyline.getCentroidEx();
             pList.add(point);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean the centre-point of your geometry or the point at the `n / 2`-position of the corresponding pointlist. If the latter how would you handle multipart-geometries?

Comment: Here I need Centre-point of line geometry, the output should be point variable.

Comment: And where is the problem? It should work with that piece of code, as far as I can estimate.

Comment: is this a duplicate of: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/187415/how-to-get-midpoint-of-polyline-using-java-arcobjects ?

Comment: I´d rather do not flag this as a duplicate because the mentioned question seems quite worse posted than this one, making it a duplicate of this one. I think the linked one is going to be deleted soon, so the duplicate would link to nothing.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user please take the [Tour] to learn about this site and its protocols.  This question appears to be a duplicate of one asked by another account a short time ago.  If both accounts belong to you then we need you to merge them ASAP using these instructions: http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: @HimBromBeere I'm confused because 95% of the content in this question was provided by you rather than its asker.  In any event, once their accounts are merged they'll be able to transfer the content they want to their earlier question triggering that to be re-opened and resulting in a smoother editing experience all round.

Comment: @PolyGeo The content I provided was given by the edit-window itself. I´m not sure why this content was not visible at all, I only changed the formatting of the code within the edit-window, I did not add any content.

Comment: @HimBromBeere That's really weird - I've checked the question's timeline and everything else in it makes sense but there is no sign of where that content came from.  I think there must have been an unrecorded near simultaneous edit by one of the user's or an anonymous account that you formatted and saved.  The formatting was recorded OK.

Comment: @PolyGeo I already wondered on the origin of that content. However if you see rev.2 and select "side-by side by markdown"  instead of "inline"  or `side-by side" you can see that this stuff was posted by OP himself. However it is weird why the rest was not added to the actual post.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Thanks for pointing that out because I forgot to look there.  I casts some more light on what happened but does not quite explain all.  On a rare weird thing like this I'm happy to call off the search for a cause and just put it down to a glitch.

Answer (score 1):

Try [ICurve.QueryPoint](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/java/api/arcobjects/com/esri/arcgis/geometry/ICurve.html#queryPoint%28int,%20double,%20boolean,%20com.esri.arcgis.geometry.IPoint%29) with `asRatio = true`, and `distanceAlongCurve = 0.5`:

> Copies to outPoint the properties of a point on the curve at a
>   specified distance from the beginning of the curve.